# Git not recognized command in Sublime Text

Tags: bash, git, sublimetext3

I have installed those below on my **Windows 10 x64**:

1. **git-bash** (portable)

   - GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
   - git version 2.27.0.windows.1
   - bash path: "C:\Users\alazt\developer-folder\git-folder\PortableGit\bin\bash.exe"
   - git path: "C:\Users\alazt\developer-folder\git-folder\PortableGit\bin\git.exe"
2. **sublime-text** (portable)

   - Sublime Text Unregistered Version 3.2.2, Build 3211

I want to use "Git" Sublime package but cannot find how to configure git path.

I get this error when I try, for example, `git fetch` command:

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I cannot find how to configure settings JSON to set the path for git.

Below settings didn't work:

```
{ "git_command": "C:\\Users\\alazt\\developer-folder\\git-folder\\PortableGit\\bin\\git.exe" }
```

or

```
{ "terminal": "C:\\Users\\alazt\\developer-folder\\git-folder\\PortableGit\\bin\\git.exe" }
```

How can I use git commands inside Sublime Text via 'Git' package?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the full path of the file you put your `"git_command"` setting in. As far as I can tell the `Git` package has no `"terminal"` setting, what made you think that it had?

Comment: It is already in full path, I didn't get what you ask. Some Sublime-related websites recommend "terminal" key to specify the path.

Comment: What is the path to the SETTINGS file containing your `"git_command"`.

Comment: `...\Sublime Text Build 3211 x64\Data\Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Git package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Git) has its own settings file called `Git.sublime-settings`, the default settings file can be seen on the [plugin's GitHub page](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/blob/master/Git.sublime-settings). The plugin does NOT store its settings in `Preferences.sublime-settings`.

Save the settings file below in your Sublime Text Packages User directory as `Git.sublime-settings`, based on your comment the path to it should be:

```
..\Sublime Text Build 3211 x64\Data\Packages\User\Git.sublime-settings
```

```json
{
    "git_command": "C:\\Users\\alazt\\developer-folder\\git-folder\\PortableGit\\bin\\git.exe"
}
```

The example Windows path given by the plugin is `"C:\bin\git.exe"` which uses single slashes `\` but, as you have already shown, double slashes `\\` are likely to be needed. However if the path fails try replacing the double slashes with single slashes.

Please note that there is no `terminal` command shown in the plugin's [Git.sublime-settings](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/blob/master/Git.sublime-settings) file.